# Spring Custom Security With MySQL And JPA Giving 403 Access Denied

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-security-rest

I am trying to access my rest api on postman by providing authentication using UserDetailsService, but each time I am firing the request every time request giving 403 Access Denied. The behavior is same for POST and GET method. I have read the other issues logged on forum but every answers says it is due to CSRF, I disabled it but issue remains same.

Complete code is on : https://github.com/afulz29/spring-security-demo.git

Please help me, I am struggling with this issue since 3 days.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer{

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN");
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
}
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping(path = "/users")
public User getUserById(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId) {
    return userService.getUserById(userId);
}

@PostMapping(path = "/users", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    return userService.addUser(user);
}
}
```

[image: Postman request]

Comment: do you anything getting printed in console? It doesn't seem to be a spring security issue. spring usually returns 401 if security doesn't allow

Comment: no error on console, Could you please help to understand what is wrong in the code. I have provided the git repository url in question.

Comment: I download the repo. but not able to import in my local. seems some issue with build as well. let me try again

Comment: I am still not able to load your project and run. getting some config issues. will update if I succeed.

Comment: ok. Thank you. Please let me know in case you identify something which is not correct.

Comment: 1) do you already have that user registered? 2) If POST /api/users is the signup endpoint, why are you not whitelisting it?

Comment: 1)Yes, I already have few users added in database some with role USER and some with ADMIN. I am only allowing the user with ADMIN role to go through the POST api. But user with ADMIN role also gives me 403. 2) Can you explain how do i need to whitelist the endpoint. If possible could you please check the code on git repository and let me know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: See my answer. Also review this repo if you need a reference: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app

Comment: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app/blob/master/src/main/java/gt/app/config/security/SecurityConfig.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see couple of problems with your security config:

1. BASIC AUTH is not enabled but you are trying to do Basic Auth in postman

Do the following to enable Basic Auth

```
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                ...
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
```

2. I guess the POST /api/users is a user registration endpoint. You must whitelist this endpoint so that anyone can register

```
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.POST,"/api/users").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                    .httpBasic();
```

Test:

Create user

```
POST: localhost:8080/api/users

{
        "userName" : "user1",
        "password": "pass"
}
```

Get user info

```
GET: localhost:8080/api/users?userId=1   //use the correct ID

With Basic Auth: userName = user1, password = pass
```

BONUS Feedback:

1. User.userName --> you might want to make this field unique
2. `@Repository` this annotation is not required in your Repository interfaces
3. UserService interface. I don't see any reason to use the interface and impl.

Comment: Thank you, I have done the changes as per suggestion and the code is working as expected now.